# Ubuntu 18.04 - Where can I find package lists to compare standard to minimal install?

Tags: system-installation, 18.04, ubuntu-minimal

I've been installing Ubuntu 18.04 and found out that there's this new option called Minimal Install. It says, "Web browser and basic utilities" will be installed, but I'm not given a specific list of removed programs.

I've searched the web and couldn't find the list . Can anyone help me with the list of missing programs in Ubuntu 18.04 minimal version compared to a normal installation?

Is there any official resource that tells the missing programs? I know there won't be programs like LibreOffice, games etc, but I need to know all programs that are removed from the minimal version.